# Canonical Transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

How can I prove that the following transformation is canonical:

$\begin{cases}\overline{q}_i=\dfrac{q_i}{Q} \\ \overline{p}_i=Qp_i-2Pq_i
\end{cases},\ i\in\overline{1,n}$

where $Q=\sum_{i=1}^n q^2_i$ and $P=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i q_i$?

I struggled a lot trying to obtain that the jacobian matrix is symplectic, but it looks too ugly. Is there any easier method the suits to this problem?

Comment: See previous question on "How to find out whether a transformation is a canonical transformation?" (http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69827)

Comment: See (http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69827)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out whether a transformation is a canonical transformation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69827/)